# Zero-one pairings between sets of vectors

Tags: nt.number-theory, matrices, convex-polytopes, root-systems, 0-1-matrices

Let
$A\subseteq V$ and
$B\subseteq V^\star$
be spanning sets in
a finite-dimensional real vector space $V$ and
its dual $V^\star$.
Suppose that
$$
\langle b,a\rangle\in\lbrace0,1\rbrace
$$
for all
$a\in A$ and
$b\in B$;
suppose that,
moreover,
$A$ and $B$ are maximal with respect to this 0-1 condition
in the following sense:
$$
A=\lbrace x\in V\mid \langle b,x\rangle\in\lbrace0,1\rbrace\ \text{for all $b\in B$}\rbrace
$$
and
$$
B=\lbrace y\in V^\star\mid \langle y,a\rangle\in\lbrace0,1\rbrace\ \text{for all $a\in A$}\rbrace.
$$
Let
$L\subseteq V$ and
$M\subseteq V^\star$
be the abelian subgroups generated by
$A$ and
$B$,
respectively.
Since
$\langle q,p\rangle\in\mathbb Z$
for $p\in L$ and $q\in M$,
we have the pairing
$$
\langle{-},{-}\rangle:M\times L\to\mathbb Z.
$$
Is it always perfect?
By ``perfect'' I mean that
any homomorphism $L\to\mathbb Z$ has the form $\langle q,{-}\rangle$
for some $q\in M$ and
any homomorphism $M\to\mathbb Z$ has the form $\langle{-},p\rangle$
for some $p\in L$.